# creating a new variable that combines several others using if else

Tags: r, if-statement, recode

I am using a large data.frame of health conditions and outcomes, I wish to combine 10 health conditions into a single condition, 
If the patient has either a, or b, c, or d, etc. then the condition would be condition one. 
I am trying to code it like this:

```
      dataset$one <-  ifelse(dataset, (dataset$a == 1)|
                            (dataset$b == 1)|
                            (dataset$c  == 1)|
                            (dataset$d  == 1),  1, 0)
```

This seems to work for the first condition, but not when I add conditions. 
Perhaps R does not allow multiple or statements? 
Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try using `ifelse(dataset, sum(dataset[c('a','b','c','d')] == 1) >= 1, 1, 0)`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `dataset` is a data frame, define the column names, `cols`, and then apply `any` across each row of  `dataset[cols] == 1` like this.  Add zero to convert the result from logical to numeric:

```
cols <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
dataset$one <- apply(dataset[cols] == 1, 1, any) + 0
```

### Notes

1. If the columns have `NA` values that you wish to exclude then add the `na.rm = TRUE` argument:

   ```
   dataset$one <- apply(dataset[cols] == 1, 1, any, na.rm = TRUE) + 0
   ```
2. The Rfast package has `rowAny` which could be used if you don't need `na.rm`:

   ```
   library(Rfast)
   dataset$one <- rowAny(dataset[cols] == 1) + 0
   ```

Comment: Rfast doesn't have a function called "anyRows"...

Comment: Have changed it to `rowAny`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Reduce` with `|`

```
dataset$one <- as.integer(Reduce(`|`, lapply(dataset[c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')], `==`, 1))
```

---

Or another option is `rowSums`

```
dataset$one <- as.integer(rowSums(dataset[c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')] == 1) > 0)
```